# How to programmatically "like" a Facebook page within an iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I want to add code to my iOS app which prompts users to "like" my app's Facebook page after they use the program X number of times. However I want to keep it as simple as possible for the user. What are the best practices for programmatically "liking" a page? Right now, I have a link to my Facebook page in the "Help" screen, but I want to make it more visible to the user and try to get more "fans."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no API to actually create a Like connection.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't really way to like anything without user's click. It's because of malicious applications/sites